# Azure SQL Server Location list is restricted

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, azure-regions

[SQL Server Location list on Enterprise is very limited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EriUW.png)

Why is it that the list is much more limited than when using a student license?

[Student license has larger list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emVjS.png)

Edit: Seems like it was a temporary issue. It wasn't just the graphical interface, I was making HTTP Requests and even those would fail because the locations weren't registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am showing full availability, including West Europe, on SQL Server (logical server)

Can you try again and see if you're still having problems? Try hard refreshing your browser <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: portal screen shot]

Comment: I tried logging out and back in, restarting browsers and all but that somehow didn't work out. Did a hard refresh this morning and all is well again.

Seems like it was just a bug. Thanks for the help :)